# Create Google Calendar event 15 minutes before start of existing Google Calendar event

Tags: google-calendar, if-this-then-that, automation

I'd like to create a new event in Calendar2 15 minutes before an event begins in Calendar1.

No errors occur, but the applet does not create an event in Calendar2.

Seems like a no brainer but I can't get the applet to do anything.

This is my trigger + action.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I read a bit on IFTTT website.

1. You should use multiple-action applet. For details see [How to create multi-action Applets](https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410084170651-How-to-create-multi-action-Applets)
2. Instead of the trigger shown in the question, I think that you should use a button, as this should be done once to handle all the events already in your calendar. To learn about buttons in IFTTT read [Button press](https://ifttt.com/do_button/triggers/do_button_new_command_common). Later, you should decide how you want to handle the events created in Calendar1 after the events in Calendar2 are created.
3. You need read [What is a query?](https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/360053502173-What-is-a-query-). This article includes a link to an example -- how lucky you are! -- to create a list of Google Calender events.

Below this line, is what I wrote before visiting the IFTTT website.

---

I'm not familiar with IFTTT (IF THIS THEN THAT), I have used it a few times a long time ago, but I have worked with triggers on low code / no code web applications for a long time.

The trigger shown will be activated 15 minutes before the Google Calendar event starts, so it will run as many events as the selected calendar.

What you need is something that runs once, it might be by clicking a button or to be scheduled to run at a certain time.

One way to what you are looking for is to collect all the calendar events, then for each of the events found, execute the core task, in this case, create a new calendar event.

I don't know if this could be done with IFTTT, but other low-code / no-code apps can do this. My favorite is Google Apps Script because it's free, and I have been using it for a long time. To start with, it requires knowing a bit of JavaScript.

I have tested Make.com. It is a no-code / low-code automation app similar to IFTTT, but I did not use it beyond the tests because I consumed the free monthly quota, and in the meantime, I could do what I needed using Google Apps Script.

I suggest you spend some time getting familiar with some high-level automation concepts, starting by understanding the different options to start an automation and common terms like triggers, collections, loops and iterations.

Typically a collection of Google Calendar events is result of a search query. One certain no code apps something like you are looking for will require multiple actions, on to get de calendars events, one to handle the loop, one to read the event properties, and another to create a new event.

Multiple steps automation might use terms like orcheststion, workflow, and alike.